# Why not CDN everything?

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, cdn

It looks like AJAX is indeed unable (at least for all practical purposes) to write foreign HTML to the current page. But what if your CDN website had, say, a JS that would simply `document.write()` everything? Then your HTML document would have nothing but a remote script.

```
<html>
<script src="https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0wm5v7i6">
</script>
</html>
```

I tried [this](https://googledrive.com/host/0B2-LlxrQ8DVAbk1IZ1E3aWxadUU/avd.html). Funny thing is, sometimes it works and other times it does a kind of security error:

[image: ss1]

**Why doesn't this work? What if, on your own website, you simply put everything on an easy host like Google Drive?**

Comment: I think the error message is extremely clear. You're accessing your page over https, so it's refusing to run script that's accessed over http.

Comment: @JL Look at the code. It's actually referencing HTTPS.

Comment: You may have put `https` in the URL, but that just causes pastebin to redirect the request to `http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0wm5v7i6`. If the host doesn't provide requests over SSL, you can't make it do so just by putting `https` in your URLs.

Comment: @JLRishe Looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, PasteBin doesn't supply content over SSL (https). You've put `https` in the URL to your script, but PasteBin just redirects this request to `http`, and the net effect is that you are trying to access a script over `http` when the page is accessed over `https`, and Chrome prevents that.

Just try going to [`https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0wm5v7i6`](https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0wm5v7i6): your browser will be redirected to [`http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0wm5v7i6`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0wm5v7i6).

Answer (score 2):

> What if, on your own website, you simply put everything on an easy host like Google Drive?

That is possible, unless

- You want control over your website and don't want to depend on the security and availibility of another site, or that somebody reports your pastebin as abuse and it gets deleted.
- You want to make proper use of security features like content security policy and don't want to allow everything from pastebin.com.
- You want search engines to find you. Although at least google does limited interpretation of JavaScript I doubt that they will handle this content the way you like.